# What is wpa_supplicant p2p correct behavior?

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa-supplicant

I have two Android devices - say, A and B.
Also I use Kali Linux device KL with `wpa_cli` running.
Both A and B just booted, Wi-Fi on, no any apps that may affect experiment are installed.

When I run `p2p_find` on KL, it does not discover A, but suddenly does discover B. It's not KL's mistake - wireshark shows probe responses from B.

An when I run `p2p_find` on A, KL become discover also A (as I expect).

I expected that device should not be discoverable untill it itself start discovering.

But now I'm not sure - what behaviour is right? Should device be discoverable even if it is not itself discovers other devices?

Comment: On the phones check Settings -> Connections -> Phone Visibility. Is that enabled on either device?

Comment: These are Android 5 and 6 devices, so there is no "Settings -> Connections" on both. But it's good idea to look into settings, thank you.